# Drupal 7: How to use a variable name from one module to another?

Tags: drupal-7

I am trying to use the variable name from one module to another using Drupal 7. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The php approach (simpleste) :
You can define your variable as global and so you can use it everywhere with global $you_var

The Drupal approach :
You define an admin form to setup your variable, and you reach it by using variable_get()